# KDE 3.5 clean session even after power loss

Tags: kde, session

I want to start every time clean session of KDE even after power loss. Now kde remember last runned apps and for example firefox run with error. Thats happens because I use Autostart to run firefox in .kde/Autostart. System is used to display information on TV. So after power gone need to be started with firefox with specified site loaded.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

did you play with KDE sessions - setup KDE to use saved session, then arrange everything and save the session